# ошибка самописного SSL: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Основной сайт и некоторые поддомены сайта работают через cloudflare. Сертификаты везде самописные, но так как работа идет через cloudflare, в браузере нет никаких ошибок

Однако есть поддомен, который я не могу пустить через cloudflare, на него я так же сделал самописный сертификат, да, я знаю, что браузер будет ругаться, но обычно есть кнопка типа:
я принимаю риски
Но в данном случае кнопки почему то нет, вот такая ошибка, как исправить?

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
На сайте sub.site.ru для защиты ваших данных обычно используется шифрование. Однако учетные данные, которые мы получили от сайта site.ru сейчас, отличаются от тех, которые он отправляет обычно.
Вероятно, вредоносный сайт пытается выдать себя за sub.site.ru, либо страница подключения к сети Wi-Fi прервала соединение. Ваша информация по-прежнему в безопасности, так как браузер Brave разорвал соединение до того, как произошел обмен данными.

Веб-сайт sub.site.ru использует механизм HSTS. Открыть сайт в настоящее время нельзя. Сбой мог быть вызван сетевой ошибкой или действиями злоумышленников. Скорее всего, сайт заработает через некоторое время.

Comment: Если вы можете контролировать домены site.ru и sub.site.ru, то почему бы вам не поставить полноценные бесплатные сертификаты от Let's Encrypt?

Comment: думал, что есть другой способ